# Solr indexing in Typo3 giving error

Tags: tomcat, typo3, solr4, lampp

While I am trying to index pages I am getting error in the solr admin screen

```
=====================================================
`11:20:50   SEVERE  SolrCore    org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=f6baa2fb88804967909bd23e6e25f770facd1cce/pages/1608/0/0/0] unknown field 'site'
11:20:51    WARNING     XMLLoader   Unknown attribute id in add:allowDups
11:20:51    WARNING     XMLLoader   Unknown attribute id in add:overwritePending
11:20:51    WARNING     XMLLoader   Unknown attribute id in add:overwriteCommitted
11:20:51    SEVERE  SolrCore    org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=f6baa2fb88804967909bd23e6e25f770facd1cce/pages/1607/0/0/0] unknown field 'site'
11:33:31    SEVERE  SolrCore    org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field type
11:33:31    SEVERE  SolrCore    org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown commit parameter 'waitFlush'`
=====================================================
```

The typo3 developer logs show the following:

```
====================================================

    /opt/lampp/steriauk/typo3conf/ext/solr/classes/indexqueue
    /class.tx_solr_indexqueue_pageindexer.php

    tx_solr_indexqueue_Item Object
    (
    [indexQueueUid:protected] => 45992
    [rootPageUid:protected] => 1
    [type:protected] => pages
    [indexingConfigurationName:protected] => pages
    [changed:protected] => 1366715241
    [indexingProperties:protected] => Array
    (
    )

    [indexingPropertiesLoaded:protected] => 1
    [hasIndexingProperties:protected] => 
    [recordUid:protected] => 209
    [record:protected] => Array
    (
    [uid] => 209
    [pid] => 205
    [t3ver_oid] => 0
    [t3ver_id] => 0
    [t3ver_wsid] => 0
    [t3ver_label] =>`
====================================================
```

I have configured the solr extension and set up looks good as per the 'Status Report' page on typo3 admin, but the errors appear and nothing gets indexed.

Could somebody suggest if there anything I am missing in setting up the solrconfig.xml and schema.xml file. Actually these are located in my solr home which is in '/var/solr../../example/solr/collection1/conf' and '/opt/lampp/htdocs/../../ext/../solr/resources/conf/' . I am confused about which of the configs is used and how solr extension in typo3 talks to the solr search engine via tomcat.

I am using:

SOLR 4.2.0
Solr extension 2.8.2
Lampp: 1.8.1
Tomcat 6

Please let me know if you need any other information as I am new to these technologies and need to set it up urgently.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

from what I see, the solr extension does not support SOLR 4.x yet.

Within the requirements the following version is the latest supported: SOLR3.6

Check out:
http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-solr/wiki/Supported_Solr_versions

Comment: With the release of Solr 4.0, a lot of the earlier options have been deprecated due to that this error is happening.